# Clarification on differentiation of a vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, self-learning, vector-fields

I am reading the book on [Introduction to Differential Geometry by Boothby](https://aetemad.iut.ac.ir/sites/aetemad.iut.ac.ir/files//files_course/william_m._boothby_an_introduction_to_differentibookfi.org_.pdf). I am unable to understand a particular concept related to Differentiation of vector fields ((Pg. 310) Chapter VII Eq 2.10)

Let $Y$ be tangent vector field on a Manifold $M$ of dimension $m$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let the local coordinates be $u=(u_1,\dots,u_m)$. Let $F_1,\dots, F_m$ be the vectors that span the tangent space of $M$. 
We can denote by $Y$ as follows:
\begin{align}
Y = \sum_{i} b^i(u) F_i
\end{align}

Let $X_{p}$  be a tangent vector at  $p$, $X_{p}=\sum a^{j} F_{j p}$

Now choose any differentiable curve  $p(t)$ with $p\left(t_{0}\right)=p$ and $(d p / d t)_{t_{0}}=X_{p}$, so that in local coordinates it is defined by $u(t)=\left(u^{1}(t), \ldots, u^{m}(t)\right)$  with $ u^{i}\left(t_{0}\right)=u_{0}^{i} \text { and }\left(d u^{i} / d t\right)_{t_{0}}=a^{i}$

Then the books says we can write 
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{d b^{k}}{d t}\right)_{t_{0}}=\sum_{j=1}^{m}\left(\frac{\partial b^{k}}{\partial u^{j}}\right)_{u_{0}} a^{j}=X_{p} b^{k}
\end{align}

I cannot understand how the second equality follows. Moreover, $\left(\frac{d b^{k}}{d t}\right)_{t_{0}}$ is a scalar and $X_p b^k$ is a vector. How can they be equal?

Comment: Remember that tangent vectors are identified with differential operators. by $X_pb^k$, they mean the derivative of $b^k$ with repect to $X_p$. If they had meant scalar multiplication $b^k$ would be on the left, not the right. This is a common mistake for newcomers. You just haven't gotten used to the notational conventions yet.

Comment: Remember that $X_p=(dp/dt)_{t_0} = dp_{t_0}(d/dt|_{t_0})$. So by def of differential map, $X_p$ act on local function $b^k(u)$ as $$X_pb^k = dp_{t_0}\Big(\frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t_0}\Big) b^k = \frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t_0}(b^k \circ p) = \frac{db^k}{dt}\Big|_{t_0}.$$  The summation formula follows by chain rule.